# Id selected in Angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularjs code in which I navigate through a collection of values :

```
<ul class="bullet-list" ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id" >
    <li><a ng-mouseover="selectedId()" ng-model="item.id" href="{{item.url}}">      {{item.software}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my controller the code is :

```
$scope.selectedId = function(){
    alert($scope.item.id);
};
```

But there's a error when it runs :
$scope.item undefined

Could you guys help me ?

Comment: `ng-mouseover="selectedId(item)"` then `$scope.selectedId = function(item){ ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
ng-mouseover="selectedId(item)"
```

And then:

```
$scope.selectedId = function(item){
  alert(item.id);
};
```

This will pass the `$scope.item` into your `$scope.selectedId` function since `item` is bound to the scope. Changes you make to the `item` inside of your function will therefore be reflected in your view.

Comment: @SérgioOliveira Under the down arrow is a little checkmark which you can click :) You can also upvote the answer with the up arrow if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object `item` on the `$scope`.  Simply pass the item in your `ng-mouseover`, like:

```
<a ng-mouseover="selectedId(item)" ...>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
$scope.selectedId = function(item) {
    alert(item.id);
}
```

Comment: Thx Tom ! For your time